# Add file format with bash

Tags: bash, rename, file-rename, batch-rename

I have a folder with couple thousand jpg files in it. The problem is that some of them are broken because they don't have a dot between the filename and "jpg" (e.g. 123jpg).

I need a script that would fix that. How do I do that?

Comment: How do you know where the filename ends and the extension starts? Is the extension always 3 characters?

Comment: `for fn in *jpg; do [ "$fn" = *".jpg" ] || mv "$fn" "${fn%jpg}.jpg"; done` ??

Comment: All files without the extension in this folder always follow the pattern "***filename***_jpg_", there are no other types of files that don't have an extension.

Comment: Either was, give the above a try, `cd` into the directory, and then just copy/paste what is posted above.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin didn't you mean `[[` ?

Comment: @PesaThe: You're correct.  David's command as shown fails (in general) with messages like `-bash: [: too many arguments` (from a login shell).  Change that to `[[` (after undoing the mayhem caused by the the `mv` occurring for all file names ending `jpg`) resolves that.  Using the glob expression from [karafka](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1435869/karakfa)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47875797/15168) allows David's solution to become: `for fn in *[^.]jpg; do mv "$fn" "${fn%jpg}.jpg"; done`, finessing the whole issue of `[` vs `[[`.

Comment: @JonathanLefflerJo yep, you are right. `[` does not support pattern matching, it will do regular globbing.

Comment: @all, yes, sorry, I meant bash `[[..`, I'm just stuck in old habits...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with the rename command

```
$ rename jpg .jpg *[^.]jpg
```

Comment: That works too, without having to remember loop and compound command syntax.

Comment: That's one of the rename commands around; there's also a Perl-based rename (sometimes called `prename`) which would be used like this: `rename 's/jpg$/.jpg/' *[^.]jpg`.  This has the merit of not changing `anyjpgfilejpg` into `any.jpgfilejpg` (though I'm not certain that's a risk with the primitive `rename` used in the question).  +1 for the good use of `*[^.]jpg` as the glob expression.